# get all values from array inside of another array

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays

i am stucked trying to get information from an array file in php. I was able to read it and convert to php array, but now i want to print the stored information in a table but always i get incorrect values.

¿how can i retrieve the information correctly?

Array:

```
array (
  'enableservice' => true,
  'putaLimit' => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
  ),
  'remoteService' => true,
  'Console' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'bConsole' => 1,
      'ConsoleReference' => 'help',
      'EnableConsole' => true,
      'ViewPermissions' => 1,
    ),
  ),
  'accountData' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'AccountName' => 'CSSName',
      'accountBalance' => 
      array (
        0 => 450440561,
        1 => 278575333,
        2 => 325290889,
        3 => 1838037277,
        4 => 155835317,
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'AccountName' => 'CSSCustomer',
      'accountBalance' => 
      array (
        0 => 5230834,
        1 => 3008402,
        2 => 3008400,
        3 => 3231485,
        4 => 9025200,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

accountData is the array which i want to show as datatable or table. I'll glad for your help

used print_r($content) to show this:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [enableservice] => 1
    [putaLimit] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
        )

    [remoteService] => 1
    [Console] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [bConsole] => 1
                    [ConsoleReference] => help
                    [EnableConsole] => 1
                    [ViewPermissions] => 1
                )

        )

    [accountData] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AccountName] => CSSName
                    [accountBalance] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 450440561
                            [1] => 278575333
                            [2] => 325290889
                            [3] => 1838037277
                            [4] => 155835317
                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [AccountName] => CSSCustomer
                    [accountBalance] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 5230834
                            [1] => 3008402
                            [2] => 3008400
                            [3] => 3231485
                            [4] => 9025200
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: please try var_dump($array) or print_r($array) to see the index of each element.

Comment: show your php code.

Comment: hello, i've updated my post, i am trying to do a table with accountData array which has two users currently in accountname and 5 values in accountBalance

Comment: Hi, @G.Romero could you check my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the array you gave and created a solution below. This solution is not the only way to do this. But it is easy to understand.

You can read further on the subject and look at other examples of using associative arrays [from the official docs.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Here's the sandbox code sample link for the solution.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/532935a21f5f80d8e6d128bed69be18096093ab2

```
<?php

$arr = array (
  'enableservice' => true,
  'putaLimit' => 
  array (
    0 => 0,
    1 => 0,
    2 => 0,
    3 => 0,
    4 => 0,
  ),
  'remoteService' => true,
  'Console' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'bConsole' => 1,
      'ConsoleReference' => 'help',
      'EnableConsole' => true,
      'ViewPermissions' => 1,
    ),
  ),
  'accountData' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'AccountName' => 'CSSName',
      'accountBalance' => 
      array (
        0 => 450440561,
        1 => 278575333,
        2 => 325290889,
        3 => 1838037277,
        4 => 155835317,
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'AccountName' => 'CSSCustomer',
      'accountBalance' => 
      array (
        0 => 5230834,
        1 => 3008402,
        2 => 3008400,
        3 => 3231485,
        4 => 9025200,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

// This is the top array key of the data you want to retrieve.
$data = $arr["accountData"];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
    
    echo $data[$i]["AccountName"];
    
    // I created another loop to retrieve all the values in the accountBalance
    foreach ($data[$i]["accountBalance"] as $item){
       echo $item;
    }
   
}
```

Comment: i did it importing from file_get_contents that's a json file but its not importing nothing
$content = file_get_contents("banksettings.cfg");
$arr = array($content);

is that wrong? i noticed mine not saying "array ()" that's why i used array(content);
printing print_r($content); is working fine to show array

Comment: @G. Romero "$arr = array($content); is that wrong?" that won't work because you are not changing the format like that. If the "banksettings.cfg" file is containing json use json_decode($content, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: finally i've got it. thank you very much!

Comment: sorry i noticed CSSName is repeated two times and CSSCustomer is not shown, why it happens? thanks

Comment: fixed it changing $item[0] to $item[$i] haha sorry

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm happy to hear you have solved this! I've also edited my answer to $data[$i]. Sorry about that.